# webapi generic class response swagger documentation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

To simplify the issue, I created a repo on GitHub for your reference.
The full code can be accessed via https://github.com/ullfindsmit/SwaggerGenIssue
And the classes mentioned below are accessible at https://github.com/ullfindsmit/SwaggerGenIssue/blob/main/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs

I created a generic class MySmartList

```
public class MySmartList<GenericType>
{
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
    public List<GenericType> data { get; set; } = new List<GenericType>();
    public int PageNum { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use the same MySmartList class to return multiple responses with different classes.

```
[Route("GetWeatherForecast")]
[HttpGet]
public MySmartList<WeatherForecast> GetWeatherForecast()
{
    MySmartList<WeatherForecast> result = new MySmartList<WeatherForecast>(); 

    result.data = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    }).ToList();

    return result;
}

[Route("GetNumbers")]
[HttpGet]
public MySmartList<int> GetNumbers()
{
    MySmartList<int> result = new MySmartList<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result.data.Add(i);
    }
    return result;
}

[Route("GetStrings")]
[HttpGet]
public MySmartList<string> GetStrings()
{
    MySmartList<string> result = new MySmartList<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        result.data.Add(new Guid().ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, when swagger generates the documentation it creates a new class for each responses.
Int32MySmartList
StringMySmartList
WeatherForecastMySmartList

[image: Classes Generated by Swagger]

How do I make it so it uses generic classes vs creating a new class for each response. On a bigger project, there would be way too many classes for no reason.

Comment: Did you find a way to make swagger work smart with generic class responses? I facing the same issues, it generate too much scheme.

Comment: I ended up writing my own code generator for this

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are witnessing is as per design. When Swagger generates the OpenAPI specification (which underpins the Swagger UI you're viewing), it needs to create unique schema definitions for each distinct model in your API. In this case, MySmartList, MySmartList, and MySmartList are all considered distinct models, not just instances of a generic class.

The auto-generated names (such as Int32MySmartList, StringMySmartList, WeatherForecastMySmartList) are generated by the Swagger UI tooling by appending the type argument to the class name for a generic class like MySmartList.

To minimize the creation of numerous classes in your Swagger documentation, you could consider limiting the usage of generics in your API responses. However, this approach would necessitate the creation of distinct response classes for each of your endpoints, which could lead to repetitive code.

If this trade-off is acceptable, you could craft specific classes like WeatherForecastList, NumberList, StringList, etc., where each of these classes would possess the identical properties of MySmartList, but with a solid type rather than the generic type. For instance:

```
public class WeatherForecastList
{
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherForecast> data { get; set; } = new List<WeatherForecast>();
    public int PageNum { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}

[Route("GetWeatherForecast")]
[HttpGet]
public WeatherForecastList GetWeatherForecast()
{
    WeatherForecastList result = new WeatherForecastList(); 

    result.data = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

This way, you can define each class yourself, giving you more control over the names of the classes in your Swagger documentation. It might lead to code duplication, but it helps maintain a consistent naming pattern in your Swagger documentation.

Comment: No, it still creates unnecessary amount of code. I need it to only create code for WeatherForecast, MySmartList and know that the response is generic/template. Becomes even more important when I am trying to generate client libraries from this definition.

Comment: @ullfindsmit Not all languages that can consume this OpenApI document have generics. Even a popular language like Go had generics in the near past. So it has to global notation that can be used by any consumer.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to repeat everything to avoid generics you can easily do this : `public class WeatherForecastList : MySmartList<WeatherForecast>`

Comment: Eldar even if I was to do `public class WeatherForecastList : MySmartList<WeatherForecast>' the issue still remains that it will create a new class for the response. Which will create (in my case) 1000+ extra classes. So that is my concern with being more efficient.